# Failed to send the message by testing the tutorial in angularjs-chat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web, pubnub

I get this error

> TypeError: self.rooms[setup.to].publish is not a function

when sending the message. I already have the keys in pubnub, what should I do to make it work? My Angular version is 1.6.6.

```
// Send Messages
$scope.send = function() {
    Messages.send({
        data: $scope.textbox
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I dunno if you use a form but try this way :

```
   <form name="form" novalidate="true" ng-submit="send()">

    $scope.send = function () {
        if ($scope.form.$valid) {
            var data = $scope.textbox;
            $scope.textbox = null;
            $scope.messages.push(data);//of push or send depend did proto
        }
    }
```

Comment: I have this form `<div ng-app="BasicChat">
    <div ng-controller="chat">
      <div ng-repeat="message in messages">
        <strong>:</strong>
        <span></span>
      </div>
      <form ng-submit="send()">
        <input ng-model="textbox">
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>`

Comment: I edit how the form need to be for the check value i change Messages by messages as you got in your loop repeat